# Nested dict comprehension

Tags: python

In the following code,

```
[{word: score_tweet(tweet) for word in tweet} for tweet in tweets]
```

I am getting a list of dicts:

```
[{u'soad': 0.0, u'&lt;3': 0.0}, {u'outros': 0.0, u'acredita': 0.0}]
```

I would like to obtain only one flat dict like:

```
{u'soad': 0.0, u'&lt;3': 0.0, u'outros': 0.0, u'acredita': 0.0}
```

How should I change my code?
Note: I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{word: score_tweet(tweet) for tweet in tweets for word in tweet}
```

Comment: Why is it so that in the expression `word: score_tweet(tweet)` which is symmetric in regard to 'tweet' and 'word', one loop has preference over the other or must go first than the other?

Comment: @elyase: Because the dict comprehension maps directly to `for tweet in tweets: for word in tweet: foo[word] = score_tweet(tweet)`, and changing the order of the `for` expressions in the comprehension corresponds to trying to write `for word in tweet: for tweet in tweets: ...`, which obviously doesn't work as `tweet` doesn't exist when you're trying to assign its elements to `word`.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `for` loop into the dict comprehension:

```
{word: score_tweet(tweet) for tweet in tweets for word in tweet}
```

Keep in mind that two `for` loops in one line are hard to read. I would do something like this instead:

```
scores = {}

for tweet in tweets:
    tweet_score = score_tweet(tweet)

    for word in tweet:
        scores[word] = tweet_score
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives a `NameError: global name 'tweet' is not defined`

Comment: @elyase: Forgot about your second loop. Thanks.

Comment: great answer, i had to chose one.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediary step.

```
words = []
tweets = ["one two", "three four"]
for tweet in tweets:
    words.extend(tweet.split())
scores = {word: score_tweet(word) for word in words}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
[{u'soad': 0.0, u'&lt;3': 0.0}, {u'outros': 0.0, u'acredita': 0.0}] 
->
{u'soad': 0.0, u'&lt;3': 0.0, u'outros': 0.0, u'acredita': 0.0}
"""
tweets_merged = {}
tweets = [{u'soad': 0.0, u'&lt;3': 0.0}, {u'outros': 0.0, u'acredita': 0.0}]
for tweet in tweets:    
    tweets_merged = dict(tweets_merged.items() + tweet.items())
print tweets_merged
```